# Jquery returns float number for position in IE10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-10, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a DIV and I use Jquery UI to make it draggable inside its parent. There are grids of 10px for its dragging movement. The problem is IE10 messes with the position of the DIV. For example, it returns 9.99999237060547 instead of 10 for the "top" property, which then prevents the draggable from being dragged to the first cell (because it 9.99999<10, and jqueryUI assumes that moving up will take the element out of its container.
Do you know how I can fix this problem? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: solved it myself by overwriting position and offset functions:

 <pre>
 (function () {
var originalOffset = $.fn.offset;
$.fn.offset = function() {
var topleft  = originalOffset.apply(this,arguments);
return {'top': Math.round(topleft.top), 'left':Math.round(topleft.left)};   
};
 })(); 
</pre>

Please let me know if there's a better solution.